# Sending picture over a socket (Java PC - Android)

Tags: java, android, image, sockets

I'm new to Java so I need help please. I'm writing an application that will onClick send a String to Server and Server needs to return an image using socket. So my client side is Android and server side is PC - java.
I think that my server side is ok (because he prints out all the system.out.print commands) but my client side is not good. Please tell my where is my mistake? Thanks!

Here is code of my Server (PC) side (socket is delivered thru function parameter):

```
    try {
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        poruka = "" + dataInputStream.readUTF();
        System.out.print(poruka);

        int bytecount = 2048;
        byte[] buf = new byte[bytecount];

        OutputStream OUT = socket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream BuffOUT = new BufferedOutputStream(OUT, bytecount);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("screenShot.jpg");

        int i = 0;
        while ((i = in.read(buf, 0, bytecount)) != -1) {
            BuffOUT.write(buf, 0, i);
            System.out.print("check" + buf[0]);
            BuffOUT.flush();
        }


        in.close();
        BuffOUT.close();
        System.out.print("over");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            socket.close();
            dataInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and here is my Client (Android) side:

```
            Socket socket = null;
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(IPadresa, 8888);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                slanje = "hy string";
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(slanje);

                FileOutputStream outToFile = new FileOutputStream("slika.jpg");

                int bytecount = 2048;
                byte[] buf = new byte[bytecount];


                InputStream IN = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream BuffIN = new BufferedInputStream(IN, bytecount)

                int i = 0;
                int filelength = 0;       
                while((i = BuffIN.read(buf, 0, bytecount)) != -1) {
                    filelength += i;
                    outToFile.write(buf, 0, i);
                    outToFile.flush();
                }


                IN.close();
                BuffIN.close();




                dataOutputStream.close();
                socket.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

MORE INFORMATIONS:
In server side I can see String that is send from Client. And I have that System.out.print("over"); command printed every time I send String to Server. Also I have System.out.print("check" + buf[0]); printed out from Server many times. So that is why I think that there is something wrong with Client side.

And my Client side doesn't throw any Exceptions... but I noticed that Client side never passed the while loop. It get stuck there.

Comment: Please tell us what makes you think there is a problem on the client side.  What happens?  Any exceptions?  What is the output from the client and server side?

Comment: I edited my question so you can read what makes me think there is a problem on client side. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "my client side is not good", and I can't see any obvious errors that would stop it working entirely.  If you could tell us what happens, that would help.

Meanwhile there are a couple of things wrong with the code you have presented:

1. You are violating industry accepted coding standards with names such as "BuffIn", "IN", "IPaddresa" and so on.  All variable names in Java must start with a lowercase letter.

   If you do this in private code that is your business.  But if you are going to show your Java code to other people, you should conform to the standards.  (And posting your code on SO is showing it to other people ...)
2. Since you are always trying to read a whole buffer's worth of data, replace `in.read(buf, 0, bytecount)` with `in.read(buf)`.
3. There is no value in using a `BufferedInputStream` or `BufferedOutputStream` if you are only going to do *large* `read` or `write` calls on it.  Even more so if you tell the stream to use the same size buffer as your the `byte[]` you are reading / writing.
4. Both your client and server side code could leak file descriptors.  On the server-side it could leak `in`.  On the client side, any or all of the streams' file descriptors could leak.

Comment: I edited my question so you can read what makes me think there is a problem on client side. Thanks for helping!